# filtering for multiple values on one column. All values must exist, else - return zero

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I would like to filter one column in a table for couple values and show results only if all those values are there. If one or more is missing, then return zero results.

example table

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | Fruit  | Color    | 
+----+--------+----------+
| 1  | apple  | red      | 
| 2  | mango  | yellow   | 
| 3  | banana | yellow   | 
+----+--------+----------+
```

example "wrong" code: (this must return 3 rows)

```
select Fruit FROM table WHERE Color = red AND Color = yellow
```

but

```
select Fruit FROM table WHERE Color = red AND Color = green
```

must return 0 rows.

(If i use `select Fruit FROM table WHERE Color = red OR Color = green` i get 1 row which is not what i need)

I am using PHP with form where user checks different checkboxes that represent different values of the same column. So when he selects multiple checkboxes, all those values should be in the result set, otherwise no result should be given.

Thank you,

Andrew

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT Fruit
FROM yourtable
WHERE Color IN ('red', 'yellow')
AND (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Color)
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE Color IN ('red', 'yellow')
) = 2
```

Another alternative:

```
SELECT Fruit FROM yourtable
WHERE Color IN ('red', 'yellow')
AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM yourtable WHERE Color = 'red')
AND EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM yourtable WHERE Color = 'yellow')
```